# disable double click on parent element when double click on children element using css or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[I created project demo from here](https://jsfiddle.net/hieuhv1990/2pnL03u8/)

When I double click on element of children, so element of parent will be trigger on the same time. I don't want double click event on element of parent trigger, so everbody can help me? Thanks

```
    <style>
    #parent {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

        #parent:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            background: green;
        }

    #children {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

        #children:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            background: blue;
        }
</style>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="children"></div>
</div>
<script>
    $('#children').dblclick(function () {
        alert('children');
    });
    $('#parent').dblclick(function () {
        alert('parent');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You have to stop propagation like "event.stopPropagation()" in children event.

Comment: **[Event bubbling](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4616694/3639582)** http://jsfiddle.net/2pnL03u8/1/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use event.stopPropagation(); for child element.

```
 $('#children').dblclick(function (event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
     alert('children');
 });
```

You can learn more about it from following link.
http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing